# Use of the passé simple in L'Étranger

Tags: passé-simple

My understanding is usually in speech in a book the author wouldn't use passé simple because they're imitating real conversations. What is the effect here when Camus writes « [Les joueurs] hurlaient et chantaient à pleins poumons que leur club ne périrait pas. Plusieurs m'ont fait des signes. L'un m'a même crié : « On les a eus »»

Also as a second question, how outdated is Camus' language? Are expressions like « à pleins poumons » still used in modern French?

Comment: Early morning here but can't see any passé simple in Camus's sentence, only *imparfait* and *passé composé* (and *périrait* conditional) .  *hurlaient et chantaient*: (*imparfait*) last a certain time and/or are repeated;  *ont fait*, *a crié* is justified here because these are punctual in the mist of the others. Will gladly write an answer if you deconfuse my confusion! // Camus doesn't sound outdated to me (but this is very subjective, some people would not write like him in the 21st century), we could have endless discussions about this and never agree.

Comment: *Crier/hurler [à pleins poumons](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/%C3%A0_pleins_poumons)* is a perfectly normal phrase in the 21st c. Maybe a little literary, people with a lesser range of vocabulary would say *crier très fort/de toutes ses forces*, [elle chante à plein poumons](https://www.francebleu.fr/infos/insolite/videozap-elle-est-toute-seule-dans-le-metro-et-chante-a-plein-poumons-jusqu-a-ce-que-1521131911). Probably more used with *respirer* in this day and age and much used with health, outdoor sport, running.

Comment: *L'Étranger* is actually famous for [_not_ using the *passé simple* in indirect speech](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/1569/why-is-the-tense-wrong-in-the-beginning-of-the-stranger).

Comment: @None Yes sorry, as Jlliagre pointed out I didn't recognise the s at the end of eus as an agreement instead of the passé simple conjugaison

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Camus doesn't use the *passé simple* which would have been the very improbable:

> *On les eut*

or

> *Nous les eûmes*

The sentence *On les a **eus**<sup>1</sup>* is still modern French, not outdated at all. Same with *à pleins poumons*, although a little bit more literary.

<sup>1</sup> <sub>Note that the past participle ***eu*** is used with the verb *avoir* so need to agree with its direct object ***les*** because the latter is located before it in the sentence.</sub>

Comment: Perhaps worth adding a quick remark on agreement on the past participle of avoir? I wonder if that's what caused the reader not to recognize it

Comment: @LukeSawczak True, I even forgot the agreement...

Answer (score 0):

**I** L'utilisation des temps dans cette œuvre de Camus est, une question complexe, liée à d'autres questions complexes et obscures qui défient toujours les  spécialistes.

> [L'imparfait avec et sans mystère](https://www.cairn.info/les-formes-du-sens--9782801111482-page-175.htm)) L’imparfait est décidément le temps le plus fascinant qui soit, le plus subtil, le plus chatoyant, en tout cas celui qui monte face à un passé simple qui ne cesse de baisser. Et c’est le temps le plus difficile à interpréter et le plus dur à manier pour l’étranger, notamment pour les étudiants germanophones. Malgré le grand nombre de travaux dont nous disposons (citons parmi beaucoup d’autres Blumenthal 1985, Pollak 1988, Tasmowsky-De Ryck 1985 et Vassant 1995), nous sommes très loin d’une description linguistique satisfaisante. Quant aux grammaires générales, la plupart sont franchement chiches en renseignements et sans commune mesure avec la complexité du phénomène (deux pages chez Grevisse 1993, un peu plus, heureusement, dans Riegel & al. 1994). Aussi ne pourra-t-il s’agir, dans ces quelques pages rédigées en l’honneur d’un fin analyste grammatical, de prendre les problèmes à bras-le-corps. Il faudra se contenter de les aborder de façon indirecte en sélectionnant quelques scénarios..…

Il existe plusieurs articles qui traitent de cette question. Le lien suivant permet de consulter l'un de ces articles : https://www.portail-litterature.fse.ulaval.ca/fichiers/camus/5_Activite_enrichissement.pdf.

**II** Le français de Camus est du français moderne, qui reste très vivant de nos jours. Une expression comme « à pleins poumons » n'a rien d'archaïche et elle a même connu dernièrement un regain de faveur ([ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%C3%A0+pleins+poumons&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=30&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%C3%A0%20pleins%20poumons%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2C%C3%A0%20pleins%20poumons%3B%2Cc0)) parmi les écrivains ; elle est utilisable dans la conversation, cultivée ou courante.